# Application CPU Usage is high in android?

Tags: android, performance

In application the CPU usage goes to 10 to 20 % then the app will be too slow,In my app fully using JSON process fetch data from server.How to reduce the CPU usage.any know pls help me.

Comment: This is a vague question, and it's almost impossible to answer, don't you think? Did you try a profiler such as traceview? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: cpu use age high in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few tools that you can use to profile your application to understand which methods are most expensive to execute.

Take a look on this articles :

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/